# How to make my domain to point to my web application?

Tags: url, web-applications, web, dns, url-routing

I have created a free domain in freedns.afraid.org as "xxx.com"
I also have a web application built on JSF2 and deployed on my local glass fish server.
The application is accessible on **localhost:4848/MyWebApp/home.jsf**.
When I replace the "localhost" with my public ip, as expected,I am able to access the application
on the internet as well. 
Now, I want to use this www.xxx.com and make sure when someone hits url www.xxx.com, my web-application should be accessible over the internet.
Please let me know  how to do it?What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can't point domain name to ip adress with port. Point domain to ip without port, and it will work like this:

`your-domain.com:4848/MyWebApp/home.jsf`

If you don't like port shown in adress bar, you can use iframe to hide it.